# Inequality with 2-norm of matrix-vector product

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, normed-spaces

With the matrix $A \in \mathbb{R}^{m \times n}$, and vector $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$, I'm trying to figure out this inequality:

$$\|Ax\|^2 \leq L\|x\|^2$$ with $L \in \mathbb{R}$, where $L$ is proposed to be the sum of the squares of the entries in the matrix.

I tried expanding to summation notation, but I'm having trouble showing the inequality:

$$
\sum_{i=1}^m \left( \sum_{j=1}^n a_{ij}x_j \right)^2 \leq \left( \sum_{i=1}^m \sum_{j=1}^n a_{ij}^2 \right) \sum_{k=1}^n x_k^2
$$

Is there some inequality that can be used with the square on the left side, since I'm assuming expanding the square will not be helpful?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be shown by the Cauchy-Schwarz Inequality, because $$\left(\sum_{i=1}^m\sum_{j=1}^n a_{ij}^2\right)\sum_{k=1}^n x_k^2 = \sum_{i=1}^m\left(\sum_{j=1}^n a_{ij}^2\sum_{k=1}^n x_k^2\right) \geq \sum_{i=1}^m\left(\sum_{j=1}^n a_{ij} x_j\right)^2  $$

Comment: Many thanks, should have seen that one.

Comment: Glad to have helped! :)

Answer (score 1):

This is  the Cauchy–Bunyakovsky–Schwarz inequality. For any given $i$, your equation becomes
$$\left(\sum_{j=1}^n a_{ij}x_j\right)^2\le\sum_{j=1}^n a_{ij}^2\sum_{k=1}^n x_k^2$$
Following [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%E2%80%93Schwarz_inequality#Rn_.28n-dimensional_Euclidean_space.29), we can start with a quadratic polynomial
$$0\le(a_{i1}y+x_1)^2+(a_{i2}y+x_2)^2+...+(a_{in}y+x_n)^2=y^2\sum_{j=1}^n a_{ij}^2+2y\left(\sum_{j=1}^n a_{ij}x_j\right)+\sum_{j=1}^n x_j^2$$ 
The polynomial is always grater or equal to $0$, which means it cannot have two real solutions. That means that the discriminant is less then $0$
$$4\left(\sum_{j=1}^n a_{ij}x_j\right)^2-4\sum_{j=1}^n a_{ij}^2\sum_{k=1}^n x_k^2\le 0$$